# GA4 custom parameter creative_format showing random (not set)

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have defined a custom dimension, to add a creative_format UTM to the URL's in our links

[image]

When reporting the data, looks like most of the times the dimension is not informed delivering the famous "not set", nonetheless in some cases the informtion is reported:

[image]

We have checked all the implementation over and over:

- Implemenation template
- Destination urls are the same
- Autotagging is on

etc

and cant seem to find how to fix it.

Any ideas?